# Unable to add Android platform to Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

How do I recover from this error?

> [Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK
>   installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: ]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install the Latest version of Android i.e 4.3/4.4

Go to SDK Manager and install the latest SDK Platform.

And try run the command again.

```
cordova platform add android
```

[image]